# Extracting words from column in pandas df using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas df column that contains English words, some were entered as eg. Ant(small,white). I want to remove the bracketed words and put the in a new column.
The code I used is written below

```
pattern = re.compile('.*\((\w+)\).*')
df_new['Context']= [re.search(pattern,i) for i in df_new.English_words.values]
```

The screenshot shows the way the table looks
[image: 1]

#### The output of the code

[image: The output of the code]

Comment: Try `df_new['Context'] = df_new['English_words'].str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)', '').str.join(', ')`

Comment: It giving an error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'                 There are also words like 'Aroma; give out', I want to move the words after the semi-colon to the context column

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to work with regular expressions in a sequence. So maybe it is easier if you first cleanse your string and apply the regular expression @WiktorStribiżew proposed, on the cleansed string.  Btw, I don't understand where your error message comes from. Do  you have a & operator somewhere in your code? I can't immagine that it is directly caused by the code above.

Comment: No there isnt any & operator in my code but this is written above the error                              ~\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py in parse(str, flags, state)
    946 
    947     try:
--> 948         p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    949     except Verbose:
    950         # the VERBOSE flag was switched on inside the pattern.  to be

Comment: I am sorry, I mistakenly left a part of former code in the top comment suggestion, try `df_new['Context'] = df_new['English_words'].str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)').str.join(', ')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. If I want to delete the words in brackets from the English_words column I can use the regex right? And the words the come after ';'

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
# Extract all occurrences of strings inside parentheses and join them with comma + space
df_new['Context'] = df_new['English_words'].str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)').str.join(', ')
# Remove them from the original column
df_new['English_words'] = df_new['English_words'].str.replace(r'\s*\([^()]+\)', '')
```

Details:

- `.str.findall(r'\(([^()]+)\)').str.join(', ')` - the `findall` part extracts all substrings between brackets and then `str.join` creates a single string out of the matches using space+comma as a separator
- `.str.replace(r'\s*\([^()]+\)', '')` - removes all occurrences of zero or more whitespaces and then a substring between parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor, it worked perfectly!